# Sum all columns - group by 1 column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I haven't been able to find this from searching but what I'm looking to do is sum all columns of a dataframe and group by 1 columns (date). My data has repative months throughout and I want to sum all columns so each month appears once.

```
a      b     c    d  
jan    1     2   1
feb    5     3   -1
mar    0    -1   0
jan    10    7   4
feb    1     5   7
mar    9     -2   8
```

Output I'm looking to achieve is:

```
a      b     c    d  
jan    11    9   5
feb    6     8   6
mar    9    -3   8
```

I've tried: `t2.groupby(['Date'])['Number Installed'].sum().reset_index()`

which I can do for each columns but i've got 23 columns and would prefer not to. Is there a simpler answer to this>

Comment: Will you please provide t2.to_dict to make it easy to copy and paste?

Comment: What would be 'Number Installed' in the dataframe of your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
sum_month=t2.groupby('a').sum()
print(sum_month)

      b  c  d
a            
feb   6  8  6
jan  11  9  5
mar   9 -3  8
```

if you want it to be sorted exactly as in your output waited then use `sort = False`

```
sum_month=t2.groupby('a',sort=False).sum()
print(sum_month)

      b  c  d
a            
jan  11  9  5
feb   6  8  6
mar   9 -3  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the dataframe sample you provided, the following code will work:

```
tf2.groupby('a').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum ***all*** columns then you only need this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'a':['jan','feb','mar','jan','feb','mar'],'b':[1,5,0,10,1,9],'c':[2,3,-1,7,5,-2],'d':[1,-1,0,4,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

grouped_df = df.groupby('a').sum())
print(grouped_df)
```

By passing .sum() as the aggregation function, it will by default sum all the columns being grouped, if you pass a certain column or an array, then it will perform the `sum` over the specified ones.
Output:

```
      b  c  d
a
feb   6  8  6
jan  11  9  5
mar   9 -3  8
```